# TextView won't show up? (Android)

Tags: android

Trying to use an integer that will increase by 1 each time the ImageButton is pressed, and in MainActivity I declared this:

```
int x = 0;
//...
private void configureImageButton() {
        ImageButton btn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                TextView ed = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.textView1); 
                ed.setText (""+x++);
            }
        });
    }
```

and in the fragment_main xml file I declared this:
(Edited to include whole fragment_main file)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.onemanbanned.firstapp.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
        android:src="@drawable/rancher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:src="@drawable/mint" />

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:ems="120" 
    android:background="#f00">

        <requestFocus />
    </TextView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

But I still get no display of the textView1 in the Graphical Layout. I am new to Android, sorry :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please post your complete layout file - i am guessing its a RelativeLayout?
I have given your layout a quick try - and looks like everything is in order. Can you try setting a background color for your textview?

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:ems="120" 
    android:background="#f00">
```

Am afraid the textview is there, but you cant see it.

Comment: Just updated the original post, and you were right :) I see a red line across the Graphic Layout now, but still no sign of the x int that should display a 0. Could that also not be visible? Would I have to set a color for the text/int whenever I use TextView? Thank you again! :)

Comment: I tried all of your code, and no issues found. http://i.imgur.com/7iIpKsQ.png

may be you can try a different color for your text and see?

Comment: Still nothing, tried CYAN and BLACK :/ I'll try cleaning the project and then go from there, and maybe try setting a larger text size? Idk...

Comment: Sure you should try what you can - I have tried your exact code and it works pretty well. Clean, Rebuild, Exit/Restart eclipse. And since your original problem has been solved, may be you could mark this as an answer?

Comment: Just an update as I'm still having the issue of the x not showing up: I changed the value on the side of the graphical layout to "x" and it displays the letter x, so something with the int being displayed is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You have your TextView and your ImageView below the ImageButton. If you want the TextView to be under the ImageView:

```
. . .
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_above="@+id/imageView1"
    . . . />

<ImageView
    . . .
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView1" />

<TextView
    . . .
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

    <requestFocus />
</TextView>
```